# How not to include the ID in the result of the query when using Left Join

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im trying to populate my listview with data from three tables `stu_tblbasicinfo`,`stu_tblfam` and `stu_tbleducbackground`
they all have the same id which is `TagID`

```
Select A.TagID , A.Surname, A.Firstname, A.Middlename, A.Course, A.Year, B.ZipCode,
    B.Province, B.Municipality, B.Barangay, A.ContactNo, A.EmailAddress, A.Birthdate,
    A.Age, A.Birthplace, A.Religion, A.Gender, A.CivilStatus, A.Spouse, C.Mothersname,
    C.M_occupation, C.M_Number, C.Fathersname, C.F_Occupation, C.F_Number,
    C.GuardianName, C.G_Occupation, C.G_Number, D.Elementary, D.E_Years, D.JuniorHigh,
    D.J_Years, Seniorhigh, D.S_Years
from stu_tblbasicinfo As A
left join stu_tblzipcode As B
    on A.Barangay = B.Barangay
inner join stu_tblfam As C
    ON A.TagID = C.TagID
inner join stu_tbleducbackground As D
    ON A.TagID = D.TagID
```

My code works but the problem is it displays 3 TagID.

The result is like this
 `TagID(studentinfo table),Surname,Firstname,Middlename,TagID(familyBackground table),MName,FName,Gname,TagID(EducBackground table),Elementary,E_years,JuniorHigh,J_Years,SeniorHigh,S_Years`

How can I make the result in this format?
`TagID,Surname,Firstname,Middlename,Mname,Fname,Gname,Elementary,E.Years,JuniorHigh,J_Years,SeniorHigh,S_Years`

Comment: your query is unreadable, please edit you question in order to better formatting your query

Comment: If you don't want a column included in the result set then don't include it in the `SELECT` clause.  How's that not obvious?

Comment: I want it included but only once, or only the TagID from one table. not three tagid from three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Just this:

```
  Select 
    A.TagID , 
    A.Surname, 
    A.Firstname, 
    A.Middlename,
    C.Mothersname,
    C.Fathersname, 
    C.GuardianName, 
    D.Elementary, 
    D.E_Years, 
    D.JuniorHigh,
    D.J_Years, 
    D.Seniorhigh,
    D.S_Years 
        from stu_tblbasicinfo As A
        left join stu_tblzipcode As B
            on A.Barangay = B.Barangay
        inner join stu_tblfam As C
            ON A.TagID = C.TagID
        inner join stu_tbleducbackground As D
            ON A.TagID = D.TagID
```